# WCF Web Service parameter

Tags: wcf, service

I have a WCF web service that implements a parameter `List<ICustomObject>`. In the generated client code, the parameter is `List<Object>`?!? How can I make it accept the `List<ICustomObject>`, as an interface, or do I have to use a concrete class? I have the concrete class marked as `[KnowType]` and `[Serializable]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use concrete class, because you should set `DataMember` and `DataContract` for it to serilize it, and with interface you can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

WCF works with anything that is expressible in XML schema - interfaces per se are not.

You need to define your lists to be lists of **concrete types** - otherwise the client will not be able to know what to do with the list and will fall back to a `List<Object>`.